# How do I change this code to make backgrounds rotate on refresh?

Tags: background, refresh

I really need your help with this one, how to change this code to random rotate 3-4 background images on page refresh? Am using basekit sitebuilder and I have limited possibilities... here is the code:

```
<style type="text/css">body{background-image:url("http://example.com/1.jpg") !important;background-repeat: no-repeat;z-index: 110;background-position:top center;background-attachment:fixed}</style>
```

Can you give me an advice?

Comment: CSS is for styling. It's not programmable in the way you need. That's Javascript's job.

Comment: Hi Marc, I don't know if you are familiar with basekit but I cannot add JavaScript in basekit(Page Specific Scripts) simply doesn't work.

Comment: doesn't matter what you're using. CSS is not programmable. If you can't use JS, then you'll have to have some OTHER way of changing the images being loaded.